# How do I stop functions from continuing on reload?

Tags: javascript, function

So I have a function to repeat a command but when I reload it, it stacks and starts to spam the command. When I end it and start it again it works as intended.

This is my code:

```
function autoRejoin() {
  ChatLib.command("j 2")
  rejoinTimer = setTimeout(autoRejoin, 5000)
}
autoRejoin()
```

Comment: We really can't help you if you don't post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We want to help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `clearTimeout(handleId)` function.

First of all, you need to declare the `rejoinTimer` variable in the global scope. Something like this:

```
var rejoinTimer = null;

function autoRejoin() {
  // ChatLib.command("j 2");

  console.log("Text...");

  rejoinTimer = setTimeout(autoRejoin, 5000);
}
```

Then, you could stop the continuous execution of the `autoRejoin()` function, by using:

```
clearTimeout(rejoinTimer);
```

See in this example:

```js
(function() {

  var rejoinTimer = null;

  function autoRejoin() {
    // ChatLib.command("j 2");

    console.log("Text...");

    rejoinTimer = setTimeout(autoRejoin, 5000);
  }

  autoRejoin();

  var btnStop = document.getElementById("btnStop");

  btnStop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(rejoinTimer);
  };
}());
```

```html
<button id="btnStop" type="button">Stop</button>
```